# Unable to produce a list to show any matches in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I am trying to make a column of a dataframe to matches (if any) to a list. A custom function called return hits has been created to that effect.

```
def returnhits(a_list, long_string):
    matches =[]
    for match in a_list:
        if any(word in long_string.split() for match in a_list):
            matches.append(match)
    return ' , '.join(matches)
```

```
qualification_list = ('Professional Certificate', 'NiTEC ', "Bachelor's Degree", 'Diploma', 'Advanced/Higher/Graduate Diploma', 'Post Graduate Diploma' , 'Professional Degree', "Master's Degree" , 'Doctorate (PhD)')
```

However I am unable to produce the desired results.

```
df['Qualifications'] = df['Other information'].apply(lambda x : returnhits(qualification_list, x))
```

Ideally if there is a match in the text it will return say NiTEC ,Professional Degree

Comment: add a `print` before `matches.append` in order to show that there is a match - what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for checking and return multi match:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Other information': ['something', ' Diploma blah NiTEC', 'other Diploma']})
qualification_list = ('Professional Certificate', 'NiTEC', "Bachelor's Degree", 'Diploma', 'Advanced/Higher/Graduate Diploma', 'Post Graduate Diploma' , 'Professional Degree', "Master's Degree" , 'Doctorate (PhD)')

def returnhits(a_list, x):
    return(' , '.join(a for a in a_list if a in x))

df['matches'] = df['Other information'].apply(lambda x : returnhits(qualification_list,x))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Other information          matches
0            something                 
1   Diploma blah NiTEC  NiTEC , Diploma
2        other Diploma          Diploma
```

Comment: Thank you! This produced the exact results I was looking for.

Comment: If you are able to help me further along, are you able to point me to any resource that will help me to get better in python programming?

Comment: @RandyChng I start with video in youtube. search for purpose and see the video,  for me seeing video is easy :))

Comment: @RandyChng if you read the comment I delete it for don't advertise any website, when you read comment tell me

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont quite understand. Are you able to pm me the link? thanks

Comment: @RandyChng what is your level in python programming?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237076/discussion-between-randy-chng-and-user1740577).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop for that, use `pandas` regex methods:

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'Other information': ['something', ' blah blah NiTEC', 'other diploma']})
qualification_list = ('Professional Certificate', 'NiTEC', "Bachelor's Degree", 'Diploma', 'Advanced/Higher/Graduate Diploma', 'Post Graduate Diploma' , 'Professional Degree', "Master's Degree" , 'Doctorate (PhD)')

df['Qualifications'] = df['Other information'].str.extract('(%s)' % '|'.join(re.escape(s) for s in qualification_list), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df
```

output:

```
  Other information Qualifications
0         something            NaN
1   blah blah NiTEC          NiTEC
2     other diploma        diploma
```